# business service calls multiple methods on the Data Access Layer each opening a connection

Tags: c#, database-connection, data-access-layer, business-logic-layer

I am doing this pseudo-code in my unitservice which is calling 2 methods of the UnitDataProvider class.

```
var units = dataProvider.GetChildrenUnits(parentId);
unit.HierarchyIndex = units.Where( u => u.TemplateId == unit.TemplateId && u.ParentId == null).Max( u => u.HierarchyIndex) + 1;
dataProvider.AddSiblingUnit(unit);
```

Every method opens a connection.

How could this be refactorized to use only 1 connection or reuse an open connection?

Or do you think its normal to a connection for each dataprovider method call?

SOLUTION: all data access logic on the database is done within the DAL not the BLL as I think the below is NO business logic for my business its just database logic.

```
public void AddSiblingUnit(Unit unit) 
        {
            if (unit.ParentId == null)
            {
                throw new OnlyOneRootNodeIsAllowedException("Only one Root node is allowed!", null);
            } // Server side check if the root is selected because 2 root units are not allowed

            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
                using (var con = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();

                    // SELECT HierarchyIndex for the new inserted sibling
                    string selectCommandText = "SELECT HierarchyIndex FROM UNIT WHERE UnitId = @UnitId"; // UnitId of the selected sibling
                    cmd.CommandText = selectCommandText;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UnitId", unit.UnitId); // the parentId which is the selected UnitId 
                    int hierarchyIndexOfSelectedSibling = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                    int hierarchyIndexOfNewSibling = hierarchyIndexOfSelectedSibling + 1;

                    // UPDATE all sibling units whose HierarchyIndex is greater than the HierarchyIndex of the selected sibling
                    string updateCommandText = "UPDATE UNIT SET HierarchyIndex = HierarchyIndex + 1 WHERE HierarchyIndex >= @HierarchyIndex AND ParentId = @ParentId";
                    cmd.CommandText = updateCommandText;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("HierarchyIndex", hierarchyIndexOfNewSibling);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ParentId", unit.ParentId);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    // INSERT new sibling
                    string insertCommandText = "INSERT INTO UNIT (Name,TemplateId,CreatedAt,HierarchyIndex,ParentId) VALUES (@Name,@TemplateId,@CreatedAt,@HierarchyIndex,@ParentId);Select Scope_Identity();";
                    cmd.CommandText = insertCommandText;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", unit.Name);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("TemplateId", unit.TemplateId);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("CreatedAt", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = unit.CreatedAt;
                    unit.UnitId = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                    trans.Complete();
                } 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a connection pool in your dataProvider class.

This would allow you to reuse connections, but if you intend for your application to be multi-threaded you **will** have problems with this approach. Unless you make sure your connection pool has a thread safe implementation, which is easier said than done.

Comment: ok the above method was not complete. Now the method has 3 dataprovider calls. A GetXX, a UpdateSiblings and the AddSibling. What do you think about using a TransactionScope in the UnitService which spans all 3 dataprovider methods. Then every dataprovider method must also pass a connection object. What do you think?

Comment: That could work but I'm curious how you will abstract this so it's not visible from the outside. Also, is the application web or desktop based?

Comment: Its an asp.net mvc web application. What do you mean with "...so its not visible from the outside..." ? The unitService.AddSibling(Unit unit) is calling now 3 dataprovider methods each passing also a connection object. The transaction is started and finished in the service. Where exactly do you see a problem? Could you please rephrase that in other words?

Comment: Why not use a single connection per request then?

Comment: Thats exactl what I said before. The TransactionScope spans 3 methods each accepting an open connection object. Was this your concern?

Comment: Ok I have totally changed my mind. Instead of introducing a new unitservice all the database logic is done within the UnitDataProvider class as incrmenting some numbers in the database and inserting stuff is not my business logic. Not bad 10ms for inserting a sibling ;-) code above if you need.